# mimic get request in postman doesn't work as expected

Tags: postman

I want to download the [following pdf](https://innovationisrael.org.il/sites/default/files/2020%20High-Tech%20Human%20Capital%20Report%20-%20Hebrew%20Version.pdf) via Postman.

I entered the URL to postman and made a GET request:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://innovationisrael.org.il/sites/default/files/2020%20High-Tech%20Human%20Capital%20Report%20-%20Hebrew%20Version.pdf'
```

I reviewed 403 Forbidden response.

I also tried to import the request from the network tab and then to make the request in postman, then I receive a 304 status code with empty body.

The imported request:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://innovationisrael.org.il/sites/default/files/2020%20High-Tech%20Human%20Capital%20Report%20-%20Hebrew%20Version.pdf' \
--header 'authority: innovationisrael.org.il' \
--header 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
--header 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
--header 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
--header 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
--header 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
--header 'accept-language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
--header 'cookie: SSESSf011814d55d1325f79eb4fc5bf454a5c=UMRu4tTqN_hBG13cGNW8ZvUrpWCThW1HvjFrfzSVi_I' \
--header 'if-none-match: "38e2fa-5c08b608caec4"' \
--header 'if-modified-since: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 08:22:16 GMT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem (I can access the file in my browser, but when I do a `GET` request in Postman, I received a 403 Forbidden response).

It seems that the website is doing some basic parsing of the `User-Agent` header in order to determine if the traffic is coming from a real browser, or from some other source. I went into my Postman headers, and modified the User-Agent to the same value that Chrome would send, and now I get response 200 OK with PDF in body.

[image]

Comment: @Spez2 That's okay, glad it was helpful :)